# Folder/File Names on Desktop in Ubuntu Over-lapping

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Alright, new Ubuntu user and I was wondering why my icons on the desktop sometimes have overlapping names. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your Ubuntu is with Unity Desktop. And pls try this in Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+ T)

> unity --reset
>
> unity --reset-icons
>
> gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1
> unity --reset.